# Sequence of image in Image wpf in c# code

Tags: c#, image, xaml, visual-studio-2013, sequence

I want show a sequence of image in a Image WPF (Syste.Windows.Controls.Image).
Between the image i want set a pause as a framerate.
In xaml i have

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="235,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

i want insert in a cycle but why i show ed stop(fps) it?

I have tryed this but don't show the image if not the last, and i don't like thread pause

```
for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
        {

      this.image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Braccio" + i + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can animate `Image.Source`, but you can create many images and run [key-frame animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742524.aspx) to change their visibility which should produce wanted effect. Did you consider to create gif instead? It will play by itself once you assign it to `Image`.

Comment: Oh, and your mistake obviously is doing whole job in UI thread at once. UI will not get updated for a whole duration, that's why you see only last *frame*. You can split animation by using `DispatcherTimer` instead of `Thread.Sleep`. Or run job in separate `Task` / `Thread` (use `BackgroundWorker`), but then you will need to *invoke* setting `Source` in UI thread.

Comment: thanks, but i need to have one image at time because i compare this image with one image of reference. I have thinked that i could show in a Image one picture, after 2ms change this picture with another ecc... so in the same time i compare the showing image with my streaming image that i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would usually do this with a timer, preferably a `DispatcherTimer`, like this:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;
private int imageIndex = 2;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    timer.Tick += TimerTick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(@"C:\Users\Pictures\Braccio" + imageIndex + ".jpg"));

    if (++imageIndex == 5)
    {
        imageIndex = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, abd if i want show 1 or N times this sequence?

Comment: Just call `timer.Stop()` whenever you want.

Comment: i put this method in frameArrived from kinect and i noticed that the velocity of frame only the first time is correct, after it goes most velocity. Do you know why?

Comment: No idea what you mean with "after it goes most velocity". Also I don't know the Kinect SDK.

Comment: @Clemens - is there any/much cost to creating a new BitmapImage each time? Any value in caching these? Or are we avoiding all the overhead by having the same actual Image control? Just wondering since I have some code that does it this way and I was unsure if there were drawbacks.

Comment: @JoshSutterfield Not sure what you mean. Even if you reuse an Image control, you would create a new BitmapSource (e.g. a BitmapImage) to set its `Source` property for every new image you are going to display.

Comment: There are only 3 distinct images in this example so, as you say, "for every new image". So you don't have to create an indefinite number of new ones, maybe caching 3 suffices. Or maybe the overhead is only incurred once you actually hook it up to Image.Source, and is never avoided by reusing the same BitmapImage objects. Probably unknown/unimportant - but that was my optimization-obsessed question for myself that sent me here.

Comment: @JoshSutterfield Forgot to mention that WPF already caches bitmaps that are loaded from Uris, unless you explicitly disable it. So the overhead of creating a new BitmapImage is neglectable.